# gvim startup slow: huge GUI delay

Tags: vim, gvim

`vim` starts up quickly. 
`gvim` takes ages, with or without loading plugins.

The `--startuptime` option shows:

```
733.162  467.301: starting GUI
733.945  000.783: reading viminfo
25801.849  25067.904: GUI delay
```

Where is that huge GUI delay coming from?

This is on Ubuntu 12.04, running Gnome with XMonad.

Comment: Which version of vim are you running? I've heard of issues with gvim versions pre 7.2 running on XMonad.

Comment: This is 7.3. I have a possible resolution: uninstall the global menu and restart. I don't know if this is a real fix, let's see if things slow back down over the next few days.